# Conditionally duplicate rows in R while changing values in a single column

Tags: r, duplication

I have a dataframe, **df**, in which some of the values in the second column, **alt**, are separated by commas:

```
ref    alt
ACTGG  A,AATGG
GGC    G,GG
GC     G
AAT    A,AA,AAA
```

Is there a way in R for me to duplicate each row that has comma-separated values in column **df$alt** such that each value is show individually? They would be duplicated number_of_commas+1 times to allow each comma-separated value to be shown once. Below is the output I'm be looking for:

```
ref    alt
ACTGG  AATGG
ACTGG  A
GGC    GG
GGC    G
GC     G
AAT    AAA
AAT    AA
AAT    A
```

Again, this would only change the values in the second column. The first column, and any other potential columns, would simply be copied.

Comment: Do you really need to duplicate rows?

Comment: @josilber Thanks for referring me to that question! I'll add the answer best fitted for this post, as the top solution on the other one doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 3):

The `concat.split.multiple` function from my "splitstackshape" package already handles this:

```
library(splitstackshape)
concat.split.multiple(df, "alt", ",", "long")
```

Because it uses `reshape`, it will result in some rows with `NA` values.

However, I would suggest checking out the updated version of the function I've been working on a. [It's much faster and you can find it here](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733). This version is like the `data.table` approach you have selected, but you can split multiple columns at a time.

With this function you can do the following:

```
## Will convert your data.frame to a data.table
cSplit(df, "alt", ",", direction="long")
#      ref   alt
# 1: ACTGG     A
# 2: ACTGG AATGG
# 3:   GGC     G
# 4:   GGC    GG
# 5:    GC     G
# 6:   AAT     A
# 7:   AAT    AA
# 8:   AAT   AAA
```

Splitting to a "wide" form is the present default:

```
cSplit(df, "alt", ",")
#      ref alt_1 alt_2 alt_3
# 1: ACTGG     A AATGG    NA
# 2:   GGC     G    GG    NA
# 3:    GC     G    NA    NA
# 4:   AAT     A    AA   AAA
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I appreciate the flexibility of this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use split-apply-combine, handling each row of `df` separately:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, seq(nrow(df))),
        function(x) data.frame(ref=x$ref, y=strsplit(x$alt, ",")[[1]])))
#       ref     y
# 1.1 ACTGG     A
# 1.2 ACTGG AATGG
# 2.1   GGC     G
# 2.2   GGC    GG
# 3      GC     G
# 4.1   AAT     A
# 4.2   AAT    AA
# 4.3   AAT   AAA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, list(alt = unlist(strsplit(as.character(alt), ','))),
         by = list(ref)]

# ref    alt
# ACTGG  AATGG
# ACTGG  A
# GGC    GG
# GGC    G
# GC     G
# AAT    AAA
# AAT    AA
# AAT    A
```